# Having issues creating an application that instantiates an object of each type and displays the details

Tags: java

First I'm new and don't know if this is against the rules but I'm looking for a little help on my homework. I don't want a full answer, just a step in the right direction. The problem is as follows:
Mick’s Wicks makes candles in various sizes. Create a class for the business named Candle that contains data fields for color, height, and price. Create get methods for all three fields. Create set methods for color and height, but not for price. Instead, when height is set, determine the price as $2 per inch. Create a child class named ScentedCandle that contains an additional data field named scent and methods to get and set it. In the child class, override the parent’s setHeight() method to set the price of a ScentedCandle object at $3 per inch. Write an application that instantiates an object of each type and displays the details. Save the files as Candle.java, ScentedCandle.java, and DemoCandles.java.

Now I believe I have done the classes correctly but the issue I'm having is the "Write an application that instantiates an object of each type and displays the details." I just dont get it. Here's my code:

```
 public class Candle {

 public static int color;                       //Declaring Variables
 public static int height;
 public static int price;


 Candle(int startColor, int startHeight, int startPrice) {    //Constructor
    color = startColor;
    height = startHeight;
    price = startPrice;

 }


 public static int getColor()  //Public methods
 {
     return color;
 }
 public void setColor(int color)
 {
     Candle.color = color;
 }
 public static int getHeight()              
 {
     return height;
 }
 public void setHeight(int height)
 {
     Candle.height = height;
 }
 public static int getPrice()
 {
     return price;
 }
 public void setPrice(int price)
 {
     Candle.price = 2 * height;
   }
  }



  public class ScentedCandle extends Candle {                 //Creating subclass to superclass Candle

  public static int scent;                                       //Delcare Variable

  public ScentedCandle(int startScent,int startColor, int startHeight,int startPrice)      {      //Constructor
    super(startColor, startHeight, startPrice);      //Calling from superclass Candle
       scent = startScent;
  }   



    public static int getScent()                                   //Public methods
  {
      return scent;
  }
  public void setScent(int scent)
  {
      ScentedCandle.scent = scent;
  }
  public static int getPrice()
  {
      return price;
  }
   @Override
  public void setPrice(int price)
  {
      Candle.price = 3 * height;
  }
  }


  public class DemoCandles {     //Here is where I'm lost and have no clue


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Candle getColor;                       //Declaring Variables
    Candle getHeight;
    Candle getPrice;
    ScentedCandle getScent;

    getColor = new Candle();
    getHeight = new Candle();
    getPrice = new Candle();
    getScent = new ScentedCandle();


   }
  }
```

Comment: You chose the wrong tag. This looks a lot like a Java question.

Comment: Your `Candle` variables should be private, else there's really no point for a getter and setter.

Comment: *static overflow* If I may, you should do some reading on `static`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to declare `price` as a product of `height` and `2`.

```
"Write an application that instantiates an object 
                           of each type and displays the details."
```

This basically mean Create a class with a `main` method in order to run your program.
In that main method, you need to instantiate your `Candle` class.
Instantiate means to create an object instance of your `Candle` class.

Something like this:

```
Object object = new Object(someInt, someInt, someInt);  // or which ever constructor you decide to you
```

In order to get the properties of the object, use your `get` methods.  If the property(data field) does not have a `get` method, get the property with something like this `Object.property`

**And do like RC said, read up on `static`. You're not using it right**

Comment: I thought I was declaring price as a product of height and 2 when I  did:  public void setPrice(int price)
 {
     Candle.price = 2 * height;
   }

Comment: I appreciate the help and yes I'm confused. How would I "when height is set, determine the price as $2 per inch"? i though maybe price = height *2 might be it but no you said not to use it?